# data type - date, int and $ in excel as blank, however load into ms SQL server as 0 (ZEROs)

Tags: sql-server, excel, vb.net, date, type-conversion

In ms SQL server I created a table; date, number and money field. They are created as  exA(date, null), exB(int, null), exC(money, null) respectively.

I tried to load the excel values into a table of the respective fields. However in excel when there are no date (blanks) it loaded as 0 (1900-01-01). I can't load blanks into the table because of the field as date, int, money. In the money column in excel it can be either blank or 0. But when I load it the blanks and 0 are the same, 0.00.

if I changed all the fields into varchar a blank is a blank and a 0 will be a 0. However it will be all text. But this is deceiving as it's not correct since number should really be integer, and date should be date. Keeping the format as it is, I would like blanks in excel as nothing /empty and 0 amount as 0.00.  Please advise.

Below are some programming ways I tried to change it, but without success. I use vb.net to load the data from excel file into sql server.

```
  If exA = "" Then
     exA = vbEmpty
  End If
  mycommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@exA", exA))
```

my program always end up stopping here at this bottom code. Can't execute it because in sql server is as int, date or money and vbEmpty is not the same data type. I tried nothing, it doesn't work either.

```
 mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Error message: Conversion failed when converting date and/ or time from character string. exA is from the excel date column. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have as an answer to my own question after doing some investigation and research. However this may not be the best answer. For example, if we have more fields (for example 200) and some can be blank and others are not. In this case there needs to be a lot of if clause. It's a work around. If there are better solutions, please share.

**Solution:** for the one's that are blank, I don't add them to the database.

```
    If exA <> "" Then
         str = "INSERT INTO bank_CK (exA, exB, exC) VALUES(@A, @B, @C)"
         cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@A", exA))
         cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@B", exB))
         cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@C", exC))
    Else
         str = "INSERT INTO bank_CK (exB, exC) VALUES(@B, @C)"
         cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@B", exB))
         cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@C", exC))
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Or I could import the data as varchar(50) or the right data type and when requested; the data is then convert from blanks to NULL or data type varchar(50) for date, integer, and money to numbers or date as I have below with an SQL statement:

```
 SELECT COALESCE(CAST(NULLIF(ISNUMERIC(moneyFIELDasTEXT), 1) AS MONEY), moneyFIELDasTEXT) as moneyFIELDasTEXT, 
    anotherFIELD,  
    CASE 
        WHEN 
            ddate <> ''
            THEN                
                ddate
    END as ddate,

    CASE
        WHEN
            twage <> ''
            THEN    
                COALESCE(CAST(NULLIF(ISNUMERIC(twage), 1) AS MONEY), twage)
    END as twage,

    CASE 
        WHEN 
            wdate <> ''
            THEN                
                cast(wdate as date)
    END as wdate,

    CASE 
        WHEN 
            ddate <> ''
            THEN                
                convert(varchar(50),ddate, 102)
    END as ddate,

    CASE
        WHEN
            tamt<> ''
            THEN    
                COALESCE(CAST(NULLIF(ISNUMERIC(tamt), 1) AS MONEY), tamt)
    END as tamt
FROM table
WHERE rdate = ''
```